# Assign default value in flutter constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class named vendor

```
class Vendor {
    int id;
    String name;
    
   Vendor({this.id , this.name});
}
```

Now I have another class person, in this class I have a list of vendors I want to set default value in person constructor:

```
class Person {
      List<Vendor> vendor;
   
      Person({this.vendor});
 }
```

I've tried this solution but it did not work

```
class Person {
       List<Vendor> vendor;
      Person({this.vendor}) : vendor = vendor ?? const [];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default values for optional constructor parameters using `=`:

```
class Foo {
  final List<String> strings;
  Foo({this.strings = const ['example']});
}

class Bar {
  final List<String> strings;
  Bar([this.strings = const ['example']]);
}

print(Foo().strings);  // prints '[example]'
print(Bar().strings);  // prints '[example]'
```

Note, values passed in as optional parameters must be `const`.